# PHP imap_fetchbody can't get HTML a tag link url

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm building a email read script, it read emails via imap, when i try to read email body using imap_fetchbody it only show texts, but email body have one link it seems not show,

This is my code

```
    $hostname = '{mail.test.com/notls}INBOX';
    $username = 'info@test.com';
    $password = 'testopw';

    /* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Email Server: ' . imap_last_error());
    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'SEEN FROM "noreply@test.com"');
if($emails) {

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);
    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        /* get information specific to this email */                
       echo $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
}
}
```

The email contents is like below

```
 We do our utmost to arrive to you on time. There may, however, 
be unexpected circumstances, causing our driver to be delayed. 
You can follow the current status of your assignment here.
```

When i read the email from mail client text **here** has a link, but when read that using php it only shows a text,

Email screen shot here
[image]
someone know what is the reason for this issue or is there need to change some parameters for get the link with url. Thank You

Comment: it is because you are taking text from mail. in a mail text and html is different parts so you need to take the structure first and then pass it in fectchbosy and then retreive result from result http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php

Comment: i used 1.2 but it return blank, when i use 2.2 the output is like this 

i trieVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAB2ElEQVR4nH2Tz0sUYRjHP7qrbiBK oKWGGEIHpYteRTTpUEcPooLdon+hQ7cudlXBq+TBgxp70IPkRdE9FUXqhgqBRakFoaDrj3Vnx+/b OzvjzGoPzDvPz+/zPN93Ju4Ok8SlmywlRMV4you8VyUVJ89TKusqaOuVHVNRAUfvzC5svwPX5Rp4 Iz1xHM6oaq7gyXhxeP+zAJKQd6D0WoDzuMZXQl6HlL0vsPI6GP/4N5w44e7lhGwzgQC8iqNf8CkZ RGvuQudLqG0Rfg5+pGBtUnoAGgAYZ0M7DE1jp5J9vwOqGyGbgYtT2Y9hY0aDH/+jy+RZAFPgCqWy Hh72hbfcnIfZ5+Co6E4r5Byb70QnKC2Db0swNaA9teiLFbjdBB8n4K+4SChn54PtXMSBh0buHA6U XGb4zVjfrRrpBMRGrtNbwfOWxGyC1iU9B3UaueeVOMjqNg6hXmSmxiwH

Comment: this is a base64 encription. may be an attachment

Comment: there is no attachment when i see on email client, also base64 decode also show wired output https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_decode/

Comment: can you send me the output?

Comment: above i pasted the output, it crops around 100 characters, do you want full output

Comment: It's a PNG file. It could also be an inline attachment for the email itself. Which means you don't see it as an attachment in an email client. Base64 has the property 4 characters encode 3 bytes. Which means you must start at the right character to decode it. If you append 1 character before `trieVBORw`, for instance `atrieVBORw` you will see it starts with the PNG header.

Comment: I can't see any attachments when i see on email client, i added screen shot of email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the multiple sections of the email. You can actually read the source code of an email. It is quite easy to follow and you will identify the different sections.

```
imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,$section);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php

```
(empty) - Entire message
0 - Message header
1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
1.2 - TEXT/HTML
2 - file.ext
```

The section you mention on the comments it is a PNG file. Some sections can be encoded in base64 as the email it is a text based protocol.

https://www.base64decode.org/

Example of an email:

```
 From: Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com> 
 To:  Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com> 
 Subject: Sample message 
 MIME-Version: 1.0 
 Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple 
 boundary" 

 This is the preamble.  It is to be ignored, though it 
 is a handy place for mail composers to include an 
 explanatory note to non-MIME compliant readers. 
 --simple boundary 

 This is implicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It does NOT end with a linebreak. 
 --simple boundary 
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 

 This is explicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It DOES end with a linebreak. 

 --simple boundary-- 
 This is the epilogue.  It is also to be ignored.
```

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html